# Related Rates calculus problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, problem-solving

For some reason I keep getting this question wrong.

Suppose a 6 feet tall man is walking away from a 15 foot tall lamp post at 5ft/s. What is the rate at which the man's shadow is moving when he is 40 ft from the lamp post.

Here is what I did: $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = 5$ The man's speed at which he is walking. We want $\dfrac{ds}{dt}$. And we can use the chain rule to get: $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = \dfrac{dx}{ds}\cdot \dfrac{ds}{dt}$        Equation (1)

Let $s$ be the position of the tip of the man's shadow. Then $x$ and $s$ are related by similar triangles:

$\dfrac{15}{x+s} = \dfrac{6}{s} \iff 15s = 6x + 6s \iff \frac{3}{2}s = x$

Now we have: $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ and $x$ in terms of $s$. $\dfrac{dx}{ds} =\dfrac{3}{2}$

Evaluating Equation (1): $5 = \dfrac{3}{2}\cdot \dfrac{ds}{dt}$ and hence $\dfrac{10}{3} = \dfrac{ds}{dt}$

The answer is supposed to be $\dfrac{25}{3}$ where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At any given time the tip of the shadow is $x+s$ ft away from the lamp post. Therefore the speed value you are looking for is
$$v=\frac{d(x+s)}{dt}=\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{ds}{dt}=\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{ds}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\frac{dx}{dt}$$
where $\alpha = \frac{h}{H}$ is the ratio of the heights of the man and the lamp post.
Hence
$$v=\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{5}}5=\frac{25}{3}$$

Since the motion is uniform I do not see the relevance of the initial condition here.

Comment: It looks great, but could you tell me where I went wrong? I would also like to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: effectively, you evaluated the speed of the shadow relatively to the walking man. It takes adding the speed of the man himself to get the answer

Comment: $\dfrac{dx}{ds}$ is the rate of change in $x$ with respect to $s$ correct?